# How to index an element of a list object in R

Tags: r, list, indexing, lapply, read.table

I'm doing the following in order to import some txt tables and keep them as list:

```
# set working directory - the folder where all selection tables are stored
hypo_selections<-list.files() # change object name according to each species
hypo_list<-lapply(hypo_selections,read.table,sep="\t",header=T) # change object name according to each species
```

I want to access one specific element, let's say hypo_list[1]. Since each element represents a table, how should I procced to access particular cells (rows and columns)?

I would like to do something like it:

```
a<-hypo_list[1]

a[1,2]
```

But I get the following error message:

```
Error in a[1, 2] : incorrect number of dimensions
```

Is there a clever way to do it?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Indexing a list is done using double bracket, i.e. `hypo_list[[1]]` (e.g. have a look here: http://www.r-tutor.com/r-introduction/list). BTW: `read.table` does not return a table but a dataframe (see value section in `?read.table`). So you will have a list of dataframes, rather than a list of table objects. The principal mechanism is identical for tables and dataframes though.

**Note**: In R, the index for the first entry is a `1` (not `0` like in some other languages).

**Dataframes**

```
l <- list(anscombe, iris)   # put dfs in list
l[[1]]             # returns anscombe dataframe

anscombe[1:2, 2]   # access first two rows and second column of dataset
[1] 10  8

l[[1]][1:2, 2]     # the same but selecting the dataframe from the list first
[1] 10  8
```

**Table objects**

```
tbl1 <- table(sample(1:5, 50, rep=T))
tbl2 <- table(sample(1:5, 50, rep=T))
l <- list(tbl1, tbl2)  # put tables in a list

tbl1[1:2]              # access first two elements of table 1
```

Now with the list

```
l[[1]]                 # access first table from the list

1  2  3  4  5 
9 11 12  9  9 

l[[1]][1:2]            # access first two elements in first table

1  2 
9 11
```

Comment: It might not be obvious for a developer that indexing starts from '1' and not '0'

Comment: @KarlP On the contrary, it is not nature to count something from 0 :)

Comment: Fair enough :-D Not obvious for developers using programming languages with a heritage from "system" languages (assembly, C, etc, up to Java, Swift), and also lisp-languages, BASIC, and just about every "generic" programming language in existence  such as perl, php, etc etc.    Specialist tools, such as Matlab, and other original non-techy languages made for a purpose such as COBOL (!) but also FORTRAN, statistical languages, etc,  typically index from 1. As does "design by committee" languages from IBM, etc.

Comment: @Karlp had said "for a developer" - so indexing from 1 is like driving your car from the back seat.

Comment: @KarlP Thank you Karl for telling me that indexes start at 1, I would have never figured this out otherwise... who would do such a terrible thing.

Answer (score 0):

`purrr::pluck` is a generalized form of the `[[` extractor which allows you to mix index types:

```r
library(purrr)
l <- list(anscombe, iris) 

# 1st element, "x2" column, 3rd and 4th element
pluck(l, 1, "x2")[3:4]
# [1] 10  8 13  9 11 14  6  4 12  7  5
```

In this instance `pluck` will return an atomic vector that can then be indexed further to get the 3rd and 4th row value. This also works because `pluck(l, 1)` returns a data frame, which are based on lists so it can be further indexed by "x2".

Since `pluck` is variadic you can pass it any number of names/indices as long as your list is nested to the same depth. There is also a `.default` argument if an element cannot be found.

`pluck` is what powers the purrr `map_*` variants used to iterate elements. Commonly used to apply a function to each element, these variants can also be used as an extractor:

```r
map(l, 2) # get the second column of every list element
```