# How to setup several jdbc connectors in one application in order to use them in a loop?

Tags: r, rjdbc

I would like to use several jdbc connections to different MSSQL databases. 
In order to be able to "loop" through all databases connected, I was trying to set up the jdbc connectors as a list.

```
conn <- list ()
conn[1] <- dbConnect(drv_mssql,"jdbc:sqlserver://server1","USER","PASSWORD")
conn[2] <- dbConnect(drv_mssql,"jdbc:sqlserver://server2","USER","PASSWORD")
```

but...

I am not able to use conn[1] in the query statement

`table <- dbGetQuery(conn[1],query_string)`

The error message is:
unable to find an inherited method for function ‘dbGetQuery’ for signature ‘"list", "character"’

Does anybody has an idea for me to get this done ?

Thank you very much in advance

Jürgen

Comment: I guess you are indexing your list in the wrong way. Try to see the output of "conn[1]" and "conn[[1]]".

See eg http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21091202/how-to-index-an-element-of-a-list-object-on-r

Comment: Dear Nieke, you are right.... Thank you very much for your hint and help. Best regards, Jürgen