# R - what does y <- dataset[,5] mean?

Tags: r

I see a lot of these [,something]

1. filename.train <- train[indexes,]
2. x <- dataset[,1:4]

Comment: Please consider [taking the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Users are more likely to help if you (1) do some [research yourself](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), and (2) learn [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) questions. This is a very basic R question. I recommend any introductory R tutorial/text. SO is not a good tutorial service, and questions such as yours usually attract down votes very quickly.

Comment: You should look up indexing for r

Comment: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/Extract.html

Comment: This book chapter on subsetting will explain it all to you https://adv-r.hadley.nz/subsetting.html very well

Comment: Duplicate of [How to index an element of a list object in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21091202/how-to-index-an-element-of-a-list-object-in-r)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **[,]** syntax is used for indexing. Your dataset is a so-called **data.frame** which implies a rectangular shape and consists of rows and columns. You can index every value of your dataframe by indicating which row(s)/column(s) you want to be returned. This is done by using the **[,]** syntax: [*rows you want*, *columns you want*]. 
If you want all rows to be returned, you simply do not define any rows - you leave it blank. For example

```
    dataset[,4]
```

returns the fourth column and **all** rows from your dataframe. You can also get multiple rows/columns by defining multiple indices in **[,]**. You can for example use **1:4** to get all the first 4 rows (1:4 is the syntax for a sequence from 1 to 4):

```
    train[1:4,]
```

Note that this returns all columns since you did not specify any column indices.
You could also combine the indexing for rows and columns:

```
    train[2:5, 7:9]
```

will return the rows 2-5 and columns 7-9.
In general what the **[,]** does is called subsetting, because it generates a subset of columns and rows from your dataframe. Internally R calls a function called **subset** which does the actually subsetting.