# How to iterate through list and use previous element?

Tags: r, math

So I am trying to take percent changes of a list of numbers. However when I try to call upon the previous element it regards it as the current element minus 1. How may I fix this?
Ex. list = (1,2,3), I want to return (n/a, 1, .5) [n/a, (2-1)/1, (3-2)/2]

```
percent_change <- function(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l){
  dataList <- list(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l)
  for(i in dataList){print((i-(i-1))/(i-1))}
}
```

Comment: YOu may need to use `for(i in 2:length(dataList)) {print(datList[[i]] - dataList[[i-1]])}`

Comment: Please provide reproducible data when you post, for example `datalist<-list(1,2,3)` and make sure everything that is code is formatted as code.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21091202/how-to-index-an-element-of-a-list-object-in-r